# jQuery.ajax() results in a 403 error

Tags: 8, ajax

I created a custom block and I was trying to use the ajax method of jQuery, but it seems that whenever I access the method of the controller, it returns a 403 error.

This is my contoller (custom_blocks/src/Controller/CustomBlocksController.php)

```
namespace Drupal\custom_blocks\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class CustomBlocksController extends ControllerBase
{
  // $variable is the wildcard from the route
  public function ajaxCallback($variable)
  { 
    return ucwords($variable);
  }
}
```

This is my routing file (custom_blocks/custom_blocks.routing.yml).

```
my.route:
  path: '/sample-page/{variable}'
  _defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\custom_blocks\Controller\CustomBlocksController::ajaxCallback'
    _permission: 'access content'
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

This is my custom JavaScript code (custom_blocks/js/command.js).

```
(function($, Drupal) {
     $('#custom-button').click(function(){
        var name = 'john doe';
        $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url: '/sample-page/' + name,
             success : function(response){
                  console.log(response);
             },   
        }, 'html');
     });
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

That's because by default Drupal only allows GET request on default controllers. In your case you should create a custom resource.

Using resources has multiple advantages:

1. No custom paths per request method
2. Access control
3. CSRF protection
4. Using the API that the REST module in Drupal 8 provides

It basically comes down to creating a class with an annotation:

```
             /**
              * @RestResource(
              *   id = "my_resource",
              *   label = @Translation("Resource label"),
              *   uri_paths = {
              *     "canonical" = "/sample-page"
              *   }
              * )
              */
             class CustomResource extends ResourceBase {
                public function post($data) {
                  // Do stuff with the posted data.
                }
             }
```

Some more elaborate examples:

[Example one](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/create-rest-resource-for-get-method-drupal-8)

[Example two](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/12/16/how-to-create-a-rest-resource-in-drupal-8/)

You will have to alter your jQuery POST request to something like:

```
 $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url: '/sample-page/',
         data: {'uid':2},
         success : function(response){
              console.log(response);
         },   
    });
```

The data you post in your jQuery request will be available in $data of your resource class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Robin, I have another question, What if I the current page has a query string on it? for example, the page is: "mysite.com/sample-page/?userid=1"

Comment: I altered my answer. I hope this clears things up

Answer (score 0):

You've got three issues in your routing file. The first is that items relating to permissions, in this case `_permission` and `_access`, should be under `requirements`, not under `defaults`. Also, it's supposed to be `defaults` not `_defaults`.

So this:

```
my.route:
  path: '/sample-page/{variable}'
  _defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\custom_blocks\Controller\CustomBlocksController::ajaxCallback'
    _permission: 'access content'
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Should be this (allow access to users with 'access content' permission):

```
my.route:
  path: '/sample-page/{variable}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\custom_blocks\Controller\CustomBlocksController::ajaxCallback'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Or this (give access to anyone):

```
my.route:
  path: '/sample-page/{variable}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\custom_blocks\Controller\CustomBlocksController::ajaxCallback'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score -1):

The controller must return right answer. I recommend to use json response.
Add `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;` to your controller.

```
 public function ajaxCallback($variable)
      { 
        return new JsonResponse(['variable' => ucwords($variable)]);
      }
```

And in your JS file `console.log(response.variable);`.

**And indicate method in your route!!**

Also i recommend to pass variables not in url.

In route file:

```
my.route:
  path: '/sample-page/'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\custom_blocks\Controller\CustomBlocksController::ajaxCallback'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
    _method: 'POST'
```

in js:

```
 (function($) {
     $('#custom-button').click(function(){
        var name = 'john doe';
      var sentdata = new Object();
      sentdata.name=name;
        $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
              data:sentdata,
             url: '/sample-page/',
             success : function(response){
                  console.log(response.name);
             },   
        }); 
     });
})(jQuery);
```

in controller:

```
//...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
//...
public function ajaxCallback()
      { 
      $name = \Drupal::request()->get('name');
        return new JsonResponse(['name' => ucwords($name)]);
      }
```

PS. Instead of drupal service wrapper (\Drupal::request()) a right way is to  [use dependency injection](https://docs.acquia.com/article/lesson-82-services-and-controllers)

Comment: Using a controller as a resource is very bad practice

Comment: We use controller as a controller not as a service resource.

Comment: Andrew, this example is clearly a REST request. When using REST calls in D8 you should use the provided resource classes en functionalities instead of writing your own custom controller...

Comment: To use ajax with restfull is just one of many way to make ajax calls. You can see examples even in drupal core (EX. comment.new_comments_node_links route). Where did you get this :"Using a controller as a resource is very bad practice"? This is a simple ajax call without using drupal ajax framework. It is not a resourse here

Comment: Asume you want antoher call, a "PUT" request. You will have to implement all permissions (PUT, DELETE, GET, POST,...) and CRSF token support by yourself. You have will have to add extra routes in your routing file. This is just complete nonsense. REST call have nothing in common with the D8 ajax framework btw...

Comment: Robin, you are actually complicating all and talking about different things. When you want just to get some data using POST request to add some data to a page you make a post ajax request. Here we don't make rest services for mobile app, we don't need PUT and DELETE requests.